# How to guarantee that a function is inlined in C++

Tags: c++, inline-functions

in C++, a function can be defined to be inline using `inline` key word. It is like the programmer has requested from the compiler to insert the complete body of the function in every place that the function is called.

But as I know compilers are not obligated to respect this request. So is there any way to guarantee that a function is inlined?

Comment: I don't think that you can _guarantee_ that. The `inline` keyword is just a recommendation for the compiler.

Comment: There are some compiler extensions (such as `__forceinline` for VC++) that will do it. But I wouldn't count on it to work on a recursion.

Comment: @Mysticial Funny, I wast _just_ looking at [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx).

Comment: Trust the optimiser to do its job.

Comment: @Rook: Trust, but verify and fix if necessary. The compiler can't always figure out the best optimisations.

Comment: I actually find that strategic use of `__declspec(noinline)` to prevent the compiler from inlining rarely called functions improves performance by reducing the code-size of critical code.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - or profile and pass the profile back to the compiler so it can actually see real usage.

Comment: @Flexo: Indeed. Then verify and fix if necessary.

Comment: See [Herb Sutter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter)'s [Inline Redux](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=184403879)

Comment: @Mike Are you actually expecting to outsmart the optimiser when it comes to *inlining*? Isn’t this one of the core competences of modern optimisers? OK, when it comes to things like auto-vectorisation and certain kinds of branch prediction, modern optimisers still struggle. But for inlining?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'm not expecting to outsmart anything; I'm saying that if optimisation is really important, then check that the optimiser is doing the right thing, and be prepared to fix things in the (hopefully unlikely) event that it doesn't. I'm rather surprised that this seems to be a controversial idea.

Comment: @Mike It’s not controversial in general, but when it comes to inlining I actually fully trust modern optimisers to know *better* than me when inlining is beneficial.

Comment: @Konrad: there's no real need to outsmart anything. Time both, if the app is slower the way the compiler does it, you consider whether it's worth forcing it to do the opposite. The only smarts involved, is guessing which functions the compiler might have got it "wrong" for in order to do the test, which is a waste of my time if the compiler got it "right". I don't need to know much about optimization to guess this, I just need to know what's hot. I *almost* fully trust modern compilers, but I *really* fully trust my profiler and stopwatch.

Comment: @Steve Okay, let me phrase it this way. On the last few compiler generations, I never had to correct my compiler’s assumptions about inlining after profiling. Other stuff, yes.

Comment: @Konrad: I guess that profile-guided optimization is pointless for inlining decisions then, if those few-generations-ago compilers that didn't have it, made correct decisions every time :-) Anyway I suspect that the heuristic "aggressively inline everything you can" is correct for almost all code on most platforms, and the remaining small proportion of cases is where the smarts (or Mike's checks) become relevant.

Comment: @Steve PGO is part of the optimiser for me. But oh well.

Comment: @Konrad: I guess I don't necessarily know what you mean by "few generations of compiler", but as I recall GCC3 didn't have PGO. Maybe it had it, but the platform I was using at the time didn't.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, I meant 4 and up. No idea which version introduced the PGO but it’s been around for quite a long time.

Comment: Anyway, I agree that normally there's no point doing this. I certainly wouldn't agree with any kind of claim that it's therefore not *worth* doing it ever. Stuff like this is worth doing a few times, if only to convince yourself it's not worth doing again. So I don't really agree with the "blindly trust the compiler" tone of some of the comments before yours. It's interesting that your experience and Mysticial's directly contradict. It's possible that someone's using the wrong flags, but otherwise maybe you work on very different kinds of code, and yours optimizes better than his.

Comment: Whats your intention to inline btw? Do you expect to get better performance, or solve any other practical problem or just you just want to know? (i know its your homework - but, just in case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `__forceinline` in VC++ and `__attribute__((always_inline))` in g++

Comment: `__forceinline` does not actually force inlining at all. Read the documentation.

Comment: @DeadMG: As far as I can make out, it forces inlining if possible; and it seems obvious to me that nothing can force it when it's not possible.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Indeed. So the answer is "It's not possible to guarantee it".

Comment: @DeadMG: For an ultra-pedantic definition of "guarantee" as "do it even if it's impossible", that's correct but useless. For a more sensible definition of "do it if possible", this is a useful answer.

Comment: I would more argue that "guarantee" involves "Do it, always". As `__forceinline` is not always, then it's not a guarantee. The reason why it's not a guarantee is interesting, but does not change the fact that it is not a guarantee.

Answer (score 8):

Nope. Actually inlining a function is a complete implementation detail, and many functions *cannot* be inlined. This makes the existence of an inline forcing mechanism impossible. Even compilers that offer keywords like `__forceinline` (VC++) *won't* inline functions with that qualifier under some circumstances. And the page carries a very apt warning about misusing this qualifier.

Answer (score 3):

As this isn't covered by the standard, it depends on the compiler you're using. The compiler's documentation will tell you if there is a feature for forcing a function to be inlined, and how to use it. The documentation should also tell you the limits of that feature, such as for recursive calls in a non-tail position.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Microsoft compiler, you may use __forceinline, as explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I do not know of a way to force inlining in g++ or other compilers.

Comment: Read the page you linked. It quite clearly states that even using `__forceinline` will not actually force the compiler to inline it.

Comment: Except the suggestion that `__forceinline` guarantees that the compiler inlines things, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: @DeadMG: Are you just complaining that the answer doesn't explicitly say that it will only work if inlining is possible? Or are you saying that `__forceinline` doesn't mean "inline the function if possible".

Comment: That page is rather out of date, as it refers to VS 2003.  (Hopefully, `inline` doesn't force internal name binding in more recent compilers.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I'm saying that the OP's question refers to a "guarantee". `__forceinline` quite clearly has conditions when in fact this is not the case. Therefore, it cannot make a guarantee and it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

By putting the definition of a function right into its declaration in the header, the function gets the highest chances to be inlined.

```
class TheClass
{
public:
    static void DoSomething () // declaration
    {
        // the function's code (definition) goes here
    };
};

// in the same header..

void DoOtherThings () // declaration
{
    // the function's code (definition) goes here
}
```

In any case, there is *no* strong guarantee, perhaps even if you use the compiler-specific keyword for inline forcing.

A 100% percent guarantee would be transforming your function into a C++ macro and using the macro instead of referring to the function. If you function has multiple lines, place a `\` (a space followed by a backslash) where you want to have a line break in your "macro-function".

Comment: What does "_By putting the definition of a function right into its declaration in the header_" mean, apart from making it `inline`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Updated the answer to illustrate what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine that there´s a way to do that. It is mainly dependant on the compiler. Another solution would be to use #define macro to define your function

Comment: Do you think using a Macro has advantages over using an inline function (other than wt u concerned here)

Comment: @Kasnel: using a macro will force the code to be inlined (since it's directly pasted inline before compilation); but it almost certainly won't give any advantage in most circumstances, and has many disadvantages of its own.

Comment: well, at least its cross compiler, so +1, compared to __forceinline. it won't give yu performance advantage, but I'd disagree with @Mike Seymour, that in most cases such directives don't cause problems. Its just not so much for c++ suitable